# What is the formal definition of a translation between theories?

Tags: logic

I've heard the expression "a translation from theory $A$ to theory $B$" thrown around a bit, but never encountered a formal definition. What is a translation between first-order theories?

Furthermore, does this make the class of all theories over a signature into a category, where the morphisms are translations?

Comment: Take a look at Caicedo's answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315399/how-does-zfc-infinitythere-is-no-infinite-set-compare-with-pa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the devil is in the details, and there is a variety of notions hereabouts of different strengths. Can I suggest two resources, both freely available online?

Giorgi Japaridze and Dick de Jongh's contribution to the *Handbook of Proof Theory* deals with 'Notions of interpretability' in their §11, starting at p. 500:  http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~japaridz/Text/prov.pdf

For category theoretic considerations, see Albert Visser's 'Categories of theories and interpretations' available at http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/lg/2008-0403-201345/preprint228.pdf