# Where is $\Bbb R$ in the von Neumann hierarchy and the constructible hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory

### Definitions

- $(a,b) := \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$
- $\Bbb N := \{n \in \infty \mid \forall A (0 \in A \land \forall n (n \in A \to n \cup \{n\} \in A) \to n \in A) \}$, where $\infty$ is the set guaranteed to exist by the axiom of infinity.
- $\Bbb Z := \Bbb N \times \Bbb N / \sim$ where $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff a+d=b+c$
- $\Bbb Q := \Bbb Z \times (\Bbb N \setminus \{0\}) / \sim$ where $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff ad = bc$
- $\Bbb R := \{S \subseteq \Bbb Q \mid \forall x \forall y (x \in S \land y < x \to y \in S) \land \\ \exists m (m \in \Bbb Q \land \forall x (x \in S \to x < m)) \land \\ \forall m (m \in S \to \exists n (n \in S \land m < n)) \}$

So $\Bbb R$ is constructed using Dedekind cuts.

### Examples

We have:
$$\varnothing = 0_\Bbb N \in \{0_\Bbb N\} \in (0_\Bbb N,0_\Bbb N) \in 0_\Bbb Z \in \{0_\Bbb Z\} \in (0_\Bbb Z,1_\Bbb N) \in 0_\Bbb Q \in 1_\Bbb R \in \Bbb R$$

Also:
$$\varnothing = 0_\Bbb N \in 1_\Bbb N \in \{1_\Bbb N\} \in (0_\Bbb Z,1_\Bbb N) \in 0_\Bbb Q \in 1_\Bbb R \in \Bbb R$$

This might faciliate the calculation.

### Question

Where is $\Bbb R$ in the [von Neumann hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) and the [constructible hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe)?

In other words, what is the least ordinal $\alpha$ and the least ordinal $\beta$ such that $\Bbb R \in L_\alpha$ and $\Bbb R \in V_\beta$?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ arrises in $V_{\omega+n}$ for some small natural $n$ whose precise value is sensitive to details of the construction of $\mathbb R$ that we don't usually care about (such as: Are elements of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ _equivalence classes_ of pairs, or canonical representativies?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm as is in my example, elements of $\Bbb Z$ are sets of pairs.

Comment: Then, unless I have a fencepost error somewhere, each element of $\mathbb Z$ is in $V_{\omega+1}$, pairs of such elements are in $V_{\omega+3}$ (assuming that we use Kuratowski pairs); each element of $\mathbb Q$ is in $V_{\omega+4}$, each Dedekind cut is in $V_{\omega+5}$, and $\mathbb R$ itself is in $V_{\omega+6}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did define pairing on the first line.

Comment: Notice that I paired elements of $\Bbb Z$ with elements of $\Bbb N_{>0}$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Intuitively say, does $L_{\omega_1^L}$ contain all the sets constructible by a finite number of formulas quantifying over any constructible sets constructed by countable recursion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question of where $\mathbb{R}$ lies in the cumulative hierarchy is sensitive to the exact definitions we use; it will always be in some $V_{\omega+n}$ for $n$ finite and small, but the precise value of $n$ may vary between reasonable choices of definition. At a glance I think your definition gives $n=6$ (Henning's calculation looks right to me), but I could be missing something.

---

However, the situation with regards to the constructible hierarchy is much more canonical and interesting:

- First of all, it is consistent that $\mathbb{R}\not\in L$: this will happen exactly when there is a non-constructible real.
- So really you want to ask about *$L$'s version of* the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}^L$. It turns out that this set shows up first in $L_{\omega_1^L+1}$ (where "$\omega_1^L$" is the least ordinal which $L$ thinks is uncountable - we may of course have $\omega_1^L<\omega_1$, just as we may have $\mathbb{R}^L\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$). The proof goes roughly:

  - First, by [the condensation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_lemma) every real in $L$ is in $L_{\omega_1^L}$.
  - Since being a real is a definable property, this means that $\mathbb{R}^L$ is a definable subset of $L_{\omega_1^L}$ - that is, $\mathbb{R}^L\in L_{\omega_1^L+1}$.
  - Finally, it can be shown (see the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536323/why-do-new-real-numbers-show-up-in-g%C3%B6dels-constructible-hierarchy)) that for every $\alpha<\omega_1^L$ there is a real $r$ in $L$ but not in $L_\alpha$. This shows that $\mathbb{R}^L\not\in L_\alpha$ for any $\alpha<\omega_1^L$, and so $\mathbb{R}^L\not\in L_{\omega_1^L}$ either.
  - Combining the previous two bullet points, we have that $\mathbb{R}^L$ appears in the $L$-hierarchy exactly at stage $\omega_1^L+1$.

Comment: For $a<\omega_1^L$ we have $(|L_a|)^L\leq \omega^L=\omega$ so $\neg (\Bbb R^L\subset L_a),$ and since $L_a$ is transitive this implies $\neg (\Bbb R^L\not \in L_a).$

Comment: I confirm the calculation that $\Bbb R \in V_{\omega+6}$

Comment: You don't need fine structure and gaps to see no countable step catches all the reals. It's a simple cardinality argument!