# Extending empty set + adjunction to interpret PA

Tags: logic, axioms, peano-axioms, alternative-set-theories

Let N = [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set) + [adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_adjunction). N [interprets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretability) [Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic).<sup>1</sup> Q + [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Axiom_of_induction) yields [PA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Peano_arithmetic_as_first-order_theory).

Does N + [epsilon-induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-induction) interpret PA? If so:

- Are they mutually interpretable, sententially equivalent, and/or bi-interpretable?
- Is there an even simpler X such that N + X interprets PA?

If not: Is there a simple X such that N + X interprets PA?

I leave the notion of "simple" deliberately vague, intending it as some kind of conceptual simplicity. (ZFfin and PA [are bi-interpretable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315451), but I seek something simpler than ZFfin.)

---

1. [*A minimal predicative set theory*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-35/issue-2/A-minimal-predicative-set-theory/10.1305/ndjfl/1094061860.full). Antonella Mancini, Franco Montagna. Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic. 35 (2): 186–203. Spring 1994.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it helps to reason semantically here.

Let $\Phi$ be the usual interpretation of $\mathsf{Q}$ in $\mathsf{N}$, and suppose $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{N}+\epsilon\mathsf{Ind}$. Then we can show that $\Phi^\mathcal{M}$ (= the model of $\mathsf{Q}$ that $\Phi$ "builds from" $\mathcal{M}$) also satisfies $\mathsf{PA}$: a definable cut in $\Phi^\mathcal{M}$ would give us a definable set with no $\epsilon$-minimal element in $\mathcal{M}$.

So not only does $\mathsf{N+\epsilon Ind}$ interpret $\mathsf{PA}$, it does so in exactly the same way that $\mathsf{N}$ interprets $\mathsf{Q}$.