# Are the natural numbers definable in ZFC-Inf

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, peano-axioms, incompleteness

While reading up on the incompleteness theorems on [this page](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#SomForThe), I came upon the statement that the incompletess theorems hold in **ZFC-Inf**. According to the page **ZFC-Inf** is 'proof-theoretically equivalent' to standard Peano Arithmetic.
This seems odd to me. Would that not mean that we can interpret the set of natural numbers together with the Successor-, Addition- and Multiplicationfunction within **ZFC-Inf**? To me the Axiom of infinity exists exactly because we would have no way of defining the set of natural numbers otherwise. So is there something I am misunderstanding, or is there really a formula $\phi_\mathbb{N}$ in **ZFC-Inf** that can define a set of natural numbers (it would not be a set in the model of course), as well as formulae $\phi_{S}, \phi_+,\phi_\times$ that define the arithmetic functions such that the axioms of **PA** are satisfied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does (ZFC-Infinity+"There is no infinite set") compare with PA?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315399/how-does-zfc-infinitythere-is-no-infinite-set-compare-with-pa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If $\mathfrak{M}\models\mathsf{ZF}$-$\mathsf{Inf}$, the "natural numbers of $\mathfrak{M}$" are the things which $\mathfrak{M}$ thinks satisfy the following formula:

> $\nu(x):\quad$ $x$ is a hereditarily transitive set and for every nonempty $y\in x$ there is some $z\in x$ such that $y=z\cup\{z\}$.

Informally, this says "$x$ is a finite ordinal." In $\mathsf{ZF}$-$\mathsf{Inf}$ alone, the standard recursive definitions of addition and multiplication of natural numbers behave as we expect. (These are tedious, though, which is why I'm omitting them; the point is that the "recursion data" witnessing any specific instance of $+$ or $\times$ is itself a finite object.)

What we *can't* do in this weaker framework is argue that the class defined by $\nu$ above is a set. But that doesn't pose an issue here.

Comment: How do you formalize '$x$ is hereditarily transitive'? Intuitively a hereditary property needs recursion to define. Or is there some characterization of hereditary transitivity that can be described with a simple formula?

Comment: @leon.fuchsler "$x$ is transitive and every element of $x$ is transitive" does the job - this is a fun exercise (and specific to transitivity).

Comment: @leon.fuchsler But note that we *do* have recursion here! Infinity isn't needed for recursion, the key driver for recursion is *replacement*.

Comment: could you clarify in what sense we have recursion here? I would think that after we introduce a notion of $\mathbb{N}$  we can prove some recursion theorem that justifies making recursive definitions. But surely defining $\mathbb{N}$ using recursion wouldn't be justified. Unsure if I am making sense.

Comment: @leon.fuchsler: It suffices to show that every nonempty definable class of ordinals has a least element.