# In ZF without the axiom of infinity are there transitive sets possible?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Somebody told me that ZF without the axiom of infinity has no transitive sets.
Probably it depends on the definition/axiom of the `emptyset' $\emptyset$? The sets $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are transitive, is it?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what they meant is that we cannot prove that there are *inductive* sets, or *infinite* transitive sets. The finite ordinals can all be constructed in $T=\mathsf{ZF}-\textrm{Infinity}$, and they are all transitive.

That said, whether we can prove in $T$ that every set (or even any hereditarily finite set) admits a transitive closure depends on how precisely we axiomatize the theory $T$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/282865/462), and the references I give there, showing that a naive axiomatization of $T$ does not prove this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the quick response!